# Some matrix calculus (differentiation)

Tags: calculus

Let $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $f(x)=||Ax-b||_2^2$. I want to show that $grad f(x)=2 A^T (Ax-b)$.
 But why is it true? I almost forgot gradient and matrix calculus, though I looked [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities) I can't figure it out. My trial:

$$grad f(x)= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=2||Ax-b||_2  \frac {\partial ||Ax-b||_2}{\partial x}$$ 
And also $$\frac {\partial ||Ax-b||_2}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial ||Ax-b||_2}{\partial Ax}\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x}=\frac{Ax-b}{||Ax-b||_2}A^T$$
So I have $gradf(x)=2(Ax-b)A^T$, what's the problem?

Comment: You've lost a factor $2$ somewhere; take $A=I$, $b=0$, then $\nabla\|x\|^2=2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $\frac{d}{dt} \mid _{t=0}f(x+th)$. You will get $2(Ax-b)\cdot Ah$, and you get the result by the fact that the conjugate of $A$ is $A^t$. If you have problems with the computations I can write them down if you want.

Comment: Isn't the direct computation hard? I thought using some chain-rules and formulas was a lot easier.

Comment: No, it takes three lines. Just write out the matrix product, you get at double sum, which is easy to differentiate wrt to t. Put t=0. Then come back to matrix notation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $g(x)=\|x\|^2$, then $\nabla g(x) = 2x$  and the obvious usage of chain rule of differentiation.

Another way is to write explcitly your function $f$  (as a polynomial) and then take partial derivative with respect to $x_i$; this would give you $i$-th component of $\nabla f$. Then, by looking at the coefficient obtained you can derive the formula in terms of matrices and vectors